# Style question: single leading underscore in a package

Tags: python, inheritance, naming-conventions, pep8

The [Python PEP 8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) gives the following guidance for a single leading underscore in method names:

> _single_leading_underscore: weak "internal use" indicator. E.g. from M import * does not import objects whose names start with an underscore.

What constitutes "internal use"? 
Is this for methods only called within a given class?

```
MyClass:

    def _internal_method(self):
        # do_something

    def public_method(self):
        self._internal_method()
```

What about inherited methods - are they still considered "internal"?

```
BaseClass:

    def _internal_method(self):
        # do something

MyClass(BaseClass):

    def public_method(self):
        self._internal_method()  # or super()._internal_method()
```

What about if the inheritance is from another module within a software package?

**file1.py**

```
BaseClass:

    def _internal_method(self):
        # do something
```

**file2.py**

```
from file1 import BaseClass

MyClass(BaseClass):

    def public_method(self):
        self._internal_method()  # or super()._internal_method()
```

All these examples are fine technically, but are they all acceptable stylistically? At what point do you say the leading underscore is not necessary/helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single leading underscore is Python's convention for "private" and "protected" variables, available as hard-implementations in some other languages.

The "internal use" language is just to say that you are reserving that name, as developer, to be used by your code as you want, and other users of your module/code can't rely on the thing tied to that name to behave the same way in further versions, or even to exist. It is just the use case for "protected" attributes, but without a hard-implementation from the language runtime: users are supposed to know that attribute/function/method can be changed without any previous warning.

So, **yes**, as long as other classes using your `_` prefixed methods are on the same code package - even if on other file, or folder (other completly distinct package), it is ok to use them.

If you have different Python packages, even if closely related, it would not be advisable to call directly on the internal stuff on the other package, style-wise.

And as for limits, sometimes there are entire modules and classes that are not supposed to be used by users of your class - and it would be somewhat impairing to prefix everything on those modules with an `_` - I'd say that it is enough to document what public interfaces to your package users are supposed to call, and add on the docs that certain parts (modules/classes/functions) are designed for "internal use and may change without note" - no need to meddle with their names.

As an illustration, I am currently developing a [set of tools/library for text-art on the terminal](https://github.com/jsbueno/terminedia/blob/master/terminedia/__init__.py) - I put everything users should call as public names in its `__init__.py` - the remaining names are meant to be "internal".